# Getting value from an array in a JSON Object in Java?

Tags: java, api

I'm fairly new to REST API calls in Java and I'm currently encountering problems with trying to get the "item" section from the JSON object (below). I guess it also confuses me that "response" is an object in an array too?/

The JSON file is below:

```
{
"version": "1.0",
"code": 200,
"request":{"text":["seafood" ], "lang": "en", "type": "stimulus"},
"response":[{
    "text": "seafood",
    "items":[
         {"item": "Shrimp", "weight": 100, "pos": "noun" }, 
         {"item": "Lobster",…
     ]
}]
}
```

I have currently managed to get the "response" part of the object using:

```java
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader( 
    new InputStreamReader(conection.getInputStream()));
StringBuffer json = new StringBuffer();
while ((readLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
    json.append(readLine);
} 
in.close();
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
try{
    JSONObject object= (JSONObject) parser.parse(json.toString());
    Object response = json.get("response");
...
```

Up to this point, I get stuck. I don't know what to do to 'response' to get to "items", and if I try to cast 'response' as a JSONObject, it will return as null?

What I want to try and do is to get each "item" in the "items" part and put it in a list.

Help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: I think it should be  `object.get("response")`. `json` is declared as `StringBuffer` but I think you mean to use the `JSONObject object` variable instead.

Comment: *Unrelated:* Don't use `StringBuffer`. Use `StringBuilder`.

Comment: What JSON library are you using? I suggest you look at its docs to determine how to use it correctly.

Comment: I believe that is [json-simple](https://github.com/fangyidong/json-simple).

Comment: Yep, json-simple :)

Comment: Made some progress! @Code-Apprentice thanks for suggesting the getJSONArray, after sorting some casting issues I found a way to get to the items (albeit very inefficiently)

Comment: @bucketfullof The links in my answer are for a different JSON library. But the idea is the same: read the documentation to find the correct classes and methods to use.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should works:

```
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
try{
    JSONObject object= (JSONObject) parser.parse(json.toString());
    JSONArray response = object.getJSONArray("response");
    JSONObject responseObject = response.getJSONObject(0);
    JSONArray expectedArray = responseObject.getJSONArray("items");
    for (int i = 0; i < expectedArray.length(); i++) {
        String item = expectedArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("item");
        String weight = expectedArray.getJSONObject(i).getInt("weight");
        ......
        //Here you can create your custom object and add to your array. For example
        list.add(new MyOwnObject(item, weight));
    }
....
```

Because response is array, not object

Answer (score -1):

You should check [the documentation for `JSONObject`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonObject.html). It describes all of the methods which are available. Note that there is no method named `get()`. Instead, you probably want to use [`getJSONArray()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonObject.html#getJsonArray-java.lang.String-)

Comment: Wrong library. That library (Java EE) doesn't have a `JSONParser` class. It has a [`JsonParser`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/stream/JsonParser.html) interface.